# I have a special line in my Grub of Ubuntu 11.10 -- Will it survive to 12 if I "do-version-upgrade?"

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, grub2, sandy-bridge

A problem with computers with Intel Sandy Bridge and Intel Celeron causes them to display only a black screen and a mouse cursor if RC6 is enabled (which it has been for all versions after 11.10). In order to get Ubuntu working on this computer (an Intel "Next Unit of Computing" or "NUC" model 847) I had to install Ubuntu 11.10, which is running fine now. After I did that, I modified Grub to change it from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 
to 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.i915_enable_rc6=0".
```

I need that `i915.i915_enable_rc6=0` bit to survive the version upgrade or I can't upgrade. **Will it survive?**

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that line will not survive and be prepared to again edit grub and or debug your intel card with the upgrade.

You may want to test a live CD before upgrading to see how your card performs.

Answer (score 0):

During the upgrade, if there is a new /etc/default/grub in the package, you will be prompted on what to do.  You can either keep your version, take the new packaged version, or see the difference between the two.  If you choose to keep your version then your settings will be preserved.  You can of course, just take the new packaged version and then edit it after to put your argument back in ( and then run `update-grub` ).

Comment: I wish that were true, but this particular Intel NUC does not respond to ESC during boot to give me a command prompt.

Comment: @user154558, so what?  You edit the file before you reboot.